# Why does this code set the variable a to 9?

Tags: loops, variables, smalltalk, parity

I am confused by this piece of code:

```
| a b c| a := 1. b := [a := a + 1]. c := [a := a - 2. b].
        10 timesRepeat: (a even ifTrue: b ifFalse: c). a
```

My assumption was that this piece of code would set `a` to `-19`. Each iteration would test if `a` was even, but `a` would be odd so `c` would be called, substracting `2` from `a` without affecting its parity. `c` would not call `b` because, if my understanding of blocks is correct, the last element of the block is returned instead of evaluated; so `c` would return `b`, but `timesRepeat` discards whatever is returned anyway so this `b` in `c` has no effect.

My assumption was proven to be wrong: this piece of code sets `a` to `9` instead. To see what's going on I modified this piece of code slightly:

```
| a b c| a := 1. b := [Transcript show: (a displayString). a := a + 1]. c := [Transcript  show: (a displayString). a := a - 2. b.].
           10 timesRepeat: (a even ifTrue: b ifFalse: c). a
```

This is what gets printed:

```
1-1012345678
```

So it would seem `b` **is** called after all? Was my assumption wrong that `b` is returned instead of called?

Let's try to check this:

```
jkl := [Transcript show: 'I am called too.'].
asdf := [Transcript show: 'I am called!'. jkl].

10 timesRepeat: asdf
```

Nope, `asdf` does not call `jkl` here:

```
I am called!I am called!I am called!I am called!I am called!I am called!I am called!I am called!I am called!I am called!
```

And anyway, if `c` was always just calling `b`, its effect would be to effectively substract `1` from `a`; but this doesn't happen. Instead, the first iteration seems to call `c` and then, mysteriously, each iteration seems to call `b` instead, even if `a` is odd!!

What's going on here??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `timesRepeat:` selector wants a block as an argument. You are calling it with an expression inside of parentheses:

```
10 timesRepeat: (a even ifTrue: b ifFalse: c).
```

It just so happens, though, that `c` is defined as the block `[a := a - 2. b]` which returns the value of `b` and that happens to be a block. So `timesRepeat:` is happy, and it executes the block `b` on each iteration in which `a` is odd. If you write it correctly as:

```
10 timesRepeat: [a even ifTrue: b ifFalse: c].
```

Then at the end, `a` will be -19 as expected.

Regarding your statement: *if my understanding of blocks is correct, the last element of the block is returned instead of evaluated*, this isn't really the case. There's no special treatment for the last statement in a block other than it's result is indeed returned as the value of the block when that block is executed. Your last statement in the block is just the name of a variable. The value of the variable just happens to be a block, but no matter what it is, just having a variable name by itself as a statement in Smalltalk just returns the value of the variable. If the variable happens to be a block, you get the block. The block is not executed.

Consider the following blocks:

```
[a := 1. b := 2. c := a+b]
```

When this block is executed, then `a` will have the value 1, `b` the value 2, and `c` the value 3. The value the block will return is the value of `c`, which is 3.

```
[a := 1. b := 2. a]
```

If you execute this block, the result will be the value of `a`, which is 1.

```
[a := 1. b := 2. c := [a+b]. c]
```

If you execute this block, the result will be the block that the variable `c` represents. It does not execute the block `c`. This is consistent with the prior example.

So, when you execute the block, `[Transcript show: 'I am called!'. jkl].`, the `jkl` at the end is not executed. It's value is just returned. If you want to execute it, you could write `asdf := [Transcript show: 'I am called!'. jkl value].` A block will execute when sent the `value` message. The result of executing block `[Transcript show: 'I am called!'. jkl value].` will be the result of executing the block `jkl`.

Answer (score 2):

I may be the only one, but I find the second sentence below a little bit obscure:

> It just so happens, though, that c is defined as the block [a := a - 2. b] which returns the value of b and that happens to be a block. *So* timesRepeat: *is happy, and it executes the block* b *on each iteration in which* a *is odd*.

The semantics of Smalltalk is:

1. Evaluate the receiver
2. Evaluate the arguments
3. Send the message

The order is crucial because evaluations may have side effects.

So, what actually happens is:

1. Receiver `10` evaluates to `10`
2. Argument `a even ifTrue: b ifFalse: c` evaluates to `b`. Side effect `a = -1`.
3. The message `10 timesRepeat: b` or `10 timesRepeat: [a := a + 1]` is sent

Hence, `a = 9`.

Comment: Thanks, Leandro. I knew after I wrote that sentence that it was cumbersome and, as you say, a bit obscure. I appreciate the clarification.